# Python: Spawn a subprocess with handles to the console, while still capturing output

Tags: python, console, subprocess, windows-console

I have rather small python script that wraps a much more complicated Java program. The python script gathers some information from the environment and then calls the java program with some appropriate arguments.

The java program needs to have access to the actual console handles, for password entry purposes. Specifically, it uses `System.console().readPassword()`, but `System.console()` is null if you use `subprocess.PIPE` from python. Not using `PIPE` isn't an option, because I need to read the output from the java program, because in certain scenarios the wrapper needs to take action based on the output.

I have been totally unable to find a way to meet both these conditions (Java has access to the real console handles, and I can still gather output from it) without resorting reams of platform-specific code. Using `pty` seems like a good angle for the Unix-verse, but the options for Windows seem limited to hundreds of lines of ctype nonsense.

Is there any way to reasonably do this (using python's stdlib)?

Comment: Python's standard library has limited support for Windows specific functionality. It's fleshed out just enough for the needs of specific modules such as subprocess, multiprocessing, asyncio, or to emulate some basic POSIX functionality in the os module. Everything else will require ctypes, CFFI, Cython, or extensions such as PyWin32. The latter has the win32console module, which you may find easier than using ctypes.

Comment: This problem is simplified if all you need to do is read a console screen buffer after the program exits. You can create a new screen buffer and pass an fd for that instead of using pipe. Then after the program exits, dump out the contents of the screen. The caveat is that you must be attached to the same console as the child. A screen buffer handle is useless otherwise.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks - could you elaborate on that second approach? Displaying the output as it is produced is also a requirement, but seems like maybe I could do the in-python equivalent of "tee" or something to get that to work?

Comment: A screen buffer can't be read as a sequential stream, i.e. it's not like reading from a pipe or pty that will block until either a read buffer is full or the channel closes. Assuming the screen is large enough that you don't have to worry about scrolling, then you could assume the application writes to stdout as a stream (i.e. not via `WriteConsoleOutput*`) and without modifying the cursor position (e.g. `SetConsoleCursorPosition`, virtual terminal escapes, or writing "\r" instead of "\r\n", ), in which case you can track the cursor position between reads. That's a lot of assumptions.